# How can i implement Twitter SSO in iOS 4.x?

Tags: ios, ios4, twitter

We have, in iOS 5, a nice way to get access to the Twitter's account, and so, implement a single sign on mechanism.

Ref.: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/Tweeting/Listings/Tweeting_TweetingViewController_m.html

But what happens if you wanna distribute an app that could run in iOS 4.x devices?.

Is it there a library somewhere to do so?.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I use for Twitter in my iOS 4+ app: https://github.com/bengottlieb/Twitter-OAuth-iPhone

You won't get the Twitter credentials from directly from the OS like in iOS 5, but once the user enters them, it will authenticate against twitter. So if you are linking a user's Twitter account with an account in your app, this would allow you to authenticate them.

Then just only use this library for your iOS 4 users and use iOS Twitter Framework for iOS 5 users.

Comment: Thanks for helping me with this one..!!

Comment: Just a side note, for anyone that might use this lib. Leave empty the Callback URL, otherwise the 'Twitter OAuth iPhone' lib will fail!.